# Adding raster created in GRASS (within QGIS) back into to GRASS (within QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, dem, viewshed

I am trying to use GRASS within QGIS - I have created a mapset etc in accordance with [these](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/01/setting-up-working-grass-environment-in.html) instructions from other posts, and I am trying to create a raster map from shapefile contour information to create a DEM (and eventually run a ZTV through r.viewshed!)

I have imported my shapefile contours into GRASS as vector using v.in.ogv.qgis and converted to raster using v.to.rast.attr.

However, as I clicked 'Show Output' to add the successfully created raster to my map (to then run r.surf.contour), my QGIS crashed, and when I open it again (and re-open QGIS mapset etc) I can't load the raster I have created.

When I navigate to the source folder, I can see that there has been a raster created, but when I drag into QGIS I get an error on compatible format.

[image]

I've also tried r.external and r.in.gdal to no avail - not recognized as a supported file format.

Is there any way I can use this raster?

It took a while to process so I'd rather not run again if I can help it!

I am a QGIS newbie.

I am using QGIS 2.10.1 PISA with OS Sierra.

EDIT: Now upgraded to QGIS 2.18 LAS PALMAS as suggested in comments, but problem still occurs.

Comment: Ther QGIS-GRASS7-plugin just landed in 2.10. Please try a more recent version. At least 2.14 or 2.16...

Comment: Thanks, hadn't realised I was so out of date. Upgraded now but same issue applies?

Comment: I use GRASS GIS outside of QGIS and data part of a mapset is usually loaded using 'd.rast'. Perhaps the same applies in QGIS. I don't think the file itself is accessible via a folder view due to way GRASS GIS saves data.